# How to create a column using different dataframe without for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a main dataframe `df` and another dataframe `ext_map`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'true': [1, 2, 3], 'billed': [4, 5, 6], 'genre':['a','b','c']})

    true    billed  genre
0    1         4    a
1    2         5    b
2    3         6    c

ext_map = pd.DataFrame(data={'label':[1,2,3], 'a':[1.1,1.2,1.3], 'b':[2.1,2.2,2.3],'c':[3.1,3.2,3.3]})

    label   a   b   c
0    1      1.1 2.1 3.1
1    2      1.2 2.2 3.2
2    3      1.3 2.3 3.3
```

I want to create a new column `new_col` in my main dataframe such that for each row in `df` I want to fetch value from columns `a`, `b`, `c` of `ext_map` based on `row.genre` and `row.true` is same as label of `ext_map`.

[Expected]

```
    true    billed  genre new_col
0    1         4      a     1.1
1    2         5      b     2.3
2    3         6      c     3.3
```

Comment: ```df['new_col'] = ext_map.lookup(df.index,ext_map.columns[1:])```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a you should be able to join a modified version of `ext_map` to `df` to do this. Some good documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

A rough example (there's probably a more terse way to do this):

You can pivot the data from a wide format to a long format (enumerating each combination of `true` and `genre`) using `pd.melt()`

```
temp = ext_map.melt(id_vars=['label'], value_vars=['a', 'b', 'c'], var_name='genre', value_name = 'new_col')
```

Which yields this result:

```
   label     genre  new_col
0      1        a      1.1
1      2        a      1.2
2      3        a      1.3
3      1        b      2.1
4      2        b      2.2
5      3        b      2.3
6      1        c      3.1
7      2        c      3.2
8      3        c      3.3
```

Then use `pd.merge()` to join the dataframes using the lookup method you mentioned:

```
df.merge(temp, left_on = ['true', 'genre'], right_on = ['label', 'variable'])
```

Giving you this result:

```
   true  billed genre  label variable  new_col
0     1       4     a      1        a      1.1
1     2       5     b      2        b      2.2
2     3       6     c      3        c      3.3
```